# Template friend declaration of a member of a dependent type

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, c++20, friend-function

In the section "13.7.4 Friends" of the C++ 20 Standard there is an example of declaring a template friend declaration of a member of a dependent type.

I have simplified the example leaving the declaration that arises a question.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A
{
    T h();
};

template <>
struct A<float *>
{
    int * h();
};

class C
{
    template <class T>
    friend int *A<T *>::h();  // grants friendship to A<int*>::h() and A<float*>::h()
};

int main()
{
}
```

But neither MS Visual Studio 2019, nor for example gcc 8.3 compiles the code.

For example the last mentioned compiler issues message

```
prog.cpp:21:24: error: member ‘int* A<T*>::h()’ declared as friend before type ‘A<T*>’ defined
  friend int *A<T *>::h();  // grants friendship to A<int*>::h() and A<float*>::h()
                        ^
```

Is it a bug of the compilers or have I missed something?

Comment: fyi - live using trunk (or latest)  clang:yes(warning); gcc:no; MSVC:yes https://godbolt.org/z/EzoWEfYPn

Comment: Using [temp.friend-example-4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.decls#temp.friend-example-4), all compilers are wrong [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d4G9h11M3): clang/gcc won't accept valid cases, msvc accept the wrong case.